# build .net class library into multiple files

Tags: libraries

i have a class library project that i dont want to split into more than one project, however i would like to compile and build it to multiple dll files instead of one big file. how could i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One assembly spanning multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225766/one-assembly-spanning-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a MultiModule Assembly.  This involves writing a custom Makefile and performing the build using nmake.

The [Multi-Module Assemblies](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Programming+C.Sharp/Part+III+The+CLR+and+the+.NET+Framework/Chapter+17.+Assemblies+and+Versioning/17.6+Multi-Module+Assemblies/) article on eTutorials is very clear and straightforward with instructions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: is there some way to avoid going through command window everytime i want to build my assemblies after i make some change? i mean i want to let the compiler know that from now on i want to out put files to be split in two this way.

Comment: I have not used this procedure, but it is documented on MSDN under "Creating a Makefile Project": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx.aspx

Comment: This process allows you to build using Visual Studio, but doesn't provide any of the nice things the IDE brings, like showing all the project files, etc.  While a pain to maintain, I could see using a .csproj (or whatever) in the IDE and using that internally for Debug builds, and only building with the makefile on Release builds.  Of course, you would need to maintain two separate projects with the same files included...

Answer (score 0):

Write your own compiler?  I don't think this is possible...
You could have a post-build step to copy and rename your dll so you would have two different dlls, but then they'd just be the same...

How would you specify which files got build into which dll?
That is kind of the whole point of having separate projects.

You can have the projects reference each other so they can use the code from the other dlls.